# Alfred command: switch finder directory in same window

Tags: macos, finder, alfred, navigation

I am an avid user of the launch application Alfred. I already have key bindings to open specific directories but when initiated, they always open the directory in a new finder window. 
Im looking for a method to change the directory of the existing finder window rather than opening a new one. Im open to native or workflow-based solutions.

Any help or ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it installing this workflow: [Open in Finder Tab](http://www.packal.org/workflow/open-finder-tab).

Just type `ot Directory` and you will have it open on a new Finder tab.

---

If you want to open a directory in the same window without open a new tab, you could edit the workflow. Go to Alfred Preferences → Workflows → Open in Finder Tab.

[image]

You must right click on Run Script and select configure. It will appear the script source. Just delete the following line and will work.

```
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "t" using command down
```

Comment: Great start. I actually have my system configured to _not_ use tabs… effectively this seems to be the same function just presented a little differently. I would like to actually _change_ the current directory with whatever directory I launch from alfred. Is there a system level conflict of some sort that prevents my desired functionality?

Comment: That is fantastic! A **BIG** thank you! My use of alfred grows by the day and this was a big obstacle in my daily workflow. Unfortunately I dont have enough rep here to give you an upvote… but thank you again.